# Kafka consumer health check

Tags: spring-kafka

Is there a simple way to say if a consumer (created with spring boot and @KafkaListener) is operating normally?
This includes - can access and poll a broker, has at least one partition assigned, etc.

I see there are ways to subscribe to different lifecycle events but this seems to be a very fragile solution.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `AdminClient` to get the current group status...

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class So56134056Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So56134056Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public NewTopic topic() {
        return new NewTopic("so56134056", 1, (short) 1);
    }

    @KafkaListener(id = "so56134056", topics = "so56134056")
    public void listen(String in) {
        System.out.println(in);
    }

    @Bean
    public ApplicationRunner runner(KafkaAdmin admin) {
        return args -> {
            try (AdminClient client = AdminClient.create(admin.getConfig())) {
                while (true) {
                    Map<String, ConsumerGroupDescription> map =
                            client.describeConsumerGroups(Collections.singletonList("so56134056")).all().get(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                    System.out.println(map);
                    System.in.read();
                }
            }
        };
    }

}
```

> `{so56134056=(groupId=so56134056, isSimpleConsumerGroup=false, members=(memberId=consumer-2-32a80e0a-2b8d-4519-b71d-671117e7eaf8, clientId=consumer-2, host=/127.0.0.1, assignment=(topicPartitions=so56134056-0)), partitionAssignor=range, state=Stable, coordinator=localhost:9092 (id: 0 rack: null))}`

We have been thinking about exposing `getLastPollTime()` to the listener container API.

`getAssignedPartitions()` has been available since 2.1.3.

Comment: Thanks! I'll probably stick with the `ConsumerGroupDescription` check with a small change - a timeout for `KafkaFuture.get()`. So if there is a networking/connectivity issue an exception can will be thrown and the check will fail. Are there any future plans for providing some health check data out of the box? I tried to google this topic and what I saw was that health check for Kafka was removed from spring-actuator as `not ready for production` and other options to be obsolete too :(

Comment: Good point (timeout); I was just testing that it returned some of the information you want. It's hard to provide a general health check for Kafka that would work for everyone; for example, if using transactions and there are not enough brokers running, the cluster should be considered down, but that is a broker setting and not available to the client.

Answer (score 1):

I know that you haven't mentioned it in your post - but beware of adding items like this to a health check if you then deploy in AWS and use such a health check for your ELB scaling environment.

For example one scenario that can happen is that your app loses connectivity to Kafka - your health check turns RED - and then elastic beanstalks begins a process of killing and re-starting your instances (which will happen continually until your Kafka instances are available again). This could be costly!

There is also a more general philosophical question on whether health checks should 'cascade failures' or not e.g. kafka is down so app connected to kafka claims it is down, the next app in the chain also does the same, etc etc. This is often more normally implemented via circuit breakers which are designed to minimise slow calls destined for failure.

Comment: Because of that, a missing Kafka should always result in `ORANGE` (WARN), not `RED` (ERROR). But nevertheless a health check of your app should always include a check of dependent services - networking problems are otherwise hard to track.

Answer (score 1):

You could check using the [AdminClient](https://kafka.apache.org/23/javadoc/index.html?org/apache/kafka/clients/admin/AdminClient.html) for the topic description.

```
final AdminClient client = AdminClient.create(kafkaConsumerFactory.getConfigurationProperties());

final String topic = "someTopicName";

final DescribeTopicsResult describeTopicsResult = client.describeTopics(Collections.singleton(topic));
final KafkaFuture<TopicDescription> future = describeTopicsResult.values().get(topic);
                    
try {
  // for healthcheck purposes we're fetching the topic description
  future.get(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
} catch (final InterruptedException | ExecutionException | TimeoutException e) {
  throw new RuntimeException("Failed to retrieve topic description for topic: " + topic, e);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I have used the last-poll-seconds-ago metric for health checks, and successfully implemented it in my application. Please check this sample for your reference.

```
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.apache.kafka.common.TopicPartition;
import org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.Health;
import org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthIndicator;
import org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.Status;
import org.springframework.kafka.config.KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry;
import org.springframework.kafka.listener.MessageListenerContainer;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.function.Function;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

@Slf4j
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class ConsumerHealthIndicator implements HealthIndicator {

private final KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry     kafkaListenerEndpointRegistry;
private final AppPropertyConfig appPropertyConfig;

@Override
public Health health() {
    final Collection<MessageListenerContainer> allListenerContainers = kafkaListenerEndpointRegistry.getAllListenerContainers();

    Optional<Double> pollInterval = allListenerContainers.stream()
            .map(MessageListenerContainer::metrics)
            .map(Map::values)
            .flatMap(Collection::stream)
            .map(Map::entrySet)
            .flatMap(Collection::stream)
            .filter(entry -> entry.getKey().name().equalsIgnoreCase("last-poll-seconds-ago"))
            .map(Map.Entry::getValue)
            .map(metric -> (Double) metric.metricValue())
            .filter(value -> value > (Double.parseDouble(appPropertyConfig.getKafkaMaxPollInterval()) / 1000))
            .findFirst();

    pollInterval.ifPresent(value -> log.info("Delay in poll {} sec", value));

    Map<String, ConsumerDetails> consumersHealth = allListenerContainers.stream()
            .map(this::buildConsumerDetails)
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(ConsumerDetails::getName, Function.identity()));

    return Health.status(pollInterval.isEmpty() ? Status.UP : Status.DOWN)
            .withDetails(consumersHealth)
            .build();
}

private ConsumerDetails buildConsumerDetails(MessageListenerContainer messageListenerContainer) {
    String partitions = messageListenerContainer.getAssignedPartitions().stream()
            .map(TopicPartition::partition)
            .map(Object::toString)
            .collect(Collectors.joining(","));

    return ConsumerDetails.builder()
            .name(messageListenerContainer.getGroupId())
            .partitions(partitions)
            .running(messageListenerContainer.isRunning())
            .build();
}

@Getter
@Builder
private static class ConsumerDetails {
    String name;
    String partitions;
    boolean running;
}
}
```

Comment: I'm afraid your heath check does not work. Metric "last-poll-seconds-ago" does not tell anything about health. Value greater than pollTimeout = 5 second indicates that consumer works noticeable long time . Value lower than 5 second does not mean anything: consumer may work quickly or Kafka may be down