# Spring Kafka - broker reconnect event

Tags: java, spring, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I am testing Kafka broker down scenarios in my application. If Kafka broker down I get `NonResponsiveConsumerEvent` event in my application like that if I bring back my Kafka broker is there any event or anything I could use to notify users saying that it is successfully reconnected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The consumer no longer blocks when the broker is down so that event is now likely to never be published. You can enable container idle events and check the status with an `AdminClient`.

[Example in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56134056/kafka-consumer-health-check/56134633#56134633).